# Help with Gambler's ruin question

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

Players A and B each have $10 at the beginning of a game in which each player bets at each play, and the game continues until one player is broke. Suppose that Player A wins on a single bet with probability p = 0.45

What is the average duration of the game?

What is the probability that Player B wins the game?

So far I have created the transition matrix on the state space $S = \begin{Bmatrix}{0,1,2,3,4}\end{Bmatrix}$ assuming that it doesn't matter how much is being bet per round (where each state of the matrix represents have a multiple of 5 in their possession, i.e. $S_0 = 0, S_4 = 20$)

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0.55&0&0.45&0&0\\0&0.55&0&0.45&0\\0&0&0.55&0&0.45\\0&0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

I do not know how to proceed from here to answer the questions that are being asked. I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Edit: Each player bets \$1 each round so the state space would be $ S = \begin{Bmatrix}0,1,2,...,20 \end{Bmatrix}$ where each state represents a dollar in possession

Comment: I think the size of the bet matters a lot. Does each player bet $5 each time? Does the winner of the game receive both bets?

Comment: @GregMartin I received clarification that each player bets \$1 each time, so there would be about 20 states in the state space and the game ends when one player goes broke so the winner does receive both bets a.k.a. is in possession of $20